# Why can't I edit text in Illustrator files from China, and how can I help it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am working with a packaging manufacturer in China. I create the files using Illustrator cs6 but after they make adjustments to my files and send the file back to me, I can't edit the text like I normally would using the cursor.

The Selection Tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) and The Direct Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd>) allow me to select a letter or words like an object. I can insert the cursor as if it looks like I will be able to edit the word or sentence normally, but the cursor just blinks and or doesn't move when I type.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Also, when sending files to places like China, should I be saving the `.ai` with a certain setting?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the text outlined? Can you select it and change the font?

Comment: Can you show us section of your work with this problem, in Outline view? `View > Outline`

Comment: I have created a screencast http://youtu.be/CylSA6BdFHg hopefully this is something that can be reversed.

Comment: It looks as if the fonts have been outlined...

Comment: Converting text to outlines is common practice when preparing a document for print (it resolves issues that arise from fonts being interpreted differently on systems that might not adequately support a font).

If you can upload a before and after document, I'd be happy to answer definitively.  Also, what changes are the manufacturer being tasked with implementing?  That might offer a further clue.

Comment: Thank you... @Hobbes and others. You guys were correct. They outline the font to apply the Spot UV but didn't tell me what was going on.  Lost in translation.  Learning a lot about retail package manufacturing in China. Little learning curve. Thanks again for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that they have outlined your font.

It is now just as much a vector graphic as any other vector object, like an illustration of a plane or a tree.

This was achieved using the " Type > Create Outline " or " Shift+Ctrl+O ".

The simple answer to your question of what you can do at this point is **nothing**.

There is no easy or even hard way to convert those sets of vector points back into any sort of recognizable font object (other than using a 3rd party program to determine which letters are there in general).

This was answered pretty well by this other GDSE question:
[How to convert text paths to editable text in an .eps file downloaded from Shutterstock?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/how-to-convert-text-paths-to-editable-text-in-an-eps-file-downloaded-from-shutt)

Comment: You are 100% right.